# VB.Net List inside a list within a loop

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm doing something for a colleague and I can't seem to store a list within a list, the first element in the List Of(List Of()) object seems to be overwritten by the previously specified list instead of adding another list inside the list, contrary as what I would want to do like: {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {and, so, forth}} where I would like to access it like so: listDim(0)(0):

```
Dim questionCont As New List(Of List(Of String))
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To numItems
        Dim questionData As New List(Of String)

        Dim getQuestionCMD As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_questionnaire WHERE ID=" + i.ToString, connection)
        Dim questionItems As OleDbDataReader = getQuestionCMD.ExecuteReader()

        While (questionItems.Read)
            questionData.Add(questionItems("question"))
            questionData.Add(questionItems("item1"))
            questionData.Add(questionItems("item2"))
            questionData.Add(questionItems("item3"))
            questionData.Add(questionItems("item4"))
            questionData.Add(questionItems("answer"))
        End While

        questionCont.Add(questionData)
        questionData.Clear()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're declaring `questionData` inside the for loop. It is being re-declared and overwritten each loop. Declare it outside of the for loop scope.

Comment: It's still the case, the List Of(List Of()) object still has one acceptable index which is 0 with questionCont(0)(0), accessing anything higher than that throws a out of bounds exception, with questionCont(1)(0).

Comment: I take it `questionData` _is_ being populated and the code inside the `While` is being hit each time?

Comment: Already fixed it. And yes, `questionData` is populated by the database entries based on a specified identifier namely the `ID` within the query statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer but I think the problem is elsewhere in your code. I tested this snippet in debug mode to prove that lists within lists work:

```
Dim lst1 As New List(Of List(Of String))
For i = 0 To 3
    Dim lst2 As New List(Of String)
    lst2.Add(i.ToString & " item 1")
    lst2.Add(i.ToString & " item 2")
    lst2.Add(i.ToString & " item 3")
    lst1.Add(lst2)
Next
Dim str = lst1(2)(2)
```

Comment: Yes, it does, work, but I can't find any contradictions that I know of, though I'm having doubts with how I handled the query statements, but I can't find what it is.

Comment: Can you run your code in debug mode? Placing a breakpoint on questionData.Clear() and checking the content of questionCont on each iteration might give you an insight..

Comment: questionCont had recognized 5 list indicated by Count=5 but each list is empty indicated by Count=0

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! It seems that the error was on my part since introducing a `.Clear()` when a `New List(Of String)` had already been declared inside the loop will clear the contents of the `List(Of String)` instance. So, removing the `.Clear()` fixed it. An oversight.